# How can we estimate the likelihood field for a particular scan in probabilistic terms?

Tags: slam, probability

[image]

I am trying to implement a scan matcher using Scan based sensor model but I cant figure out how to estimate likelihood for a particular scan. Is there any implementation available ? Would be thankful for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like ROS has a few packages (in rough order of apparent usefulness):

- [Scan matcher](http://wiki.ros.org/canonical_scan_matcher)
- [laser scan matcher](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_scan_matcher)
- [Local map](http://wiki.ros.org/local_map)
- [crsm-slam](http://wiki.ros.org/crsm_slam)
- [mrpt-localization](http://wiki.ros.org/mrpt_localization)
- [amcl](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl)

Comment: thnx for your answer @combo . AMCL package contains the implementation I am looking for.